# 500 error while connecting to mongodb

Tags: php

I have this code that i am using to try and connect to my mongodb on ubuntu 16 server

```
<?php
$uri = "mongodb://admin:admin123@localhost:27017/mydb";

   // connect to mongodb
   $m = new MongoClient($uri);
   echo "Connection to database successfully";

   // select a database
   $db = $m->mydb;
   echo "Database mydb selected";
   $collection = $db->mycol;
   echo "Collection selected succsessfully";

   $document = array( 
      "title" => "MongoDB", 
      "description" => "database", 
      "likes" => 100,
      "url" => "http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/",
      "by", "tutorials point"
   );

   $collection->insert($document);
   echo "Document inserted successfully";
?>
```

Every time i run the script i get the error

```
The 004.000.0.000 page isn’t working

004.000.0.000 is currently unable to handle this request.

HTTP ERROR 500
```

Why cant i connect to the database?.

Comment: Just a Note: **MongoClient** _This extension that defines this method is deprecated. Instead, the MongoDB extension should be used._ [From the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mongoclient.construct.php)

Comment: This dont work too `$m = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");
   echo "Connection to database successfully";`

Answer (score 0):

Check your php logs, you might see a more specific error.. Also verify that mongo is running by connecting to it from the command line.

Comment: I have given up fixing it and instead used nodejs. There are errors specific to ubuntu 16.04 that regards php7.